# How to fix dpkg: error processing fusion-icon?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

This is what I got after upgrading Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04:

```
santos@santos:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.   
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y   

Setting up fusion-icon (0.1.0-2ubuntu2) ... Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2372, in <module> main() File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2366, in main  
    rv = action.run(global_options)   File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 1529, in run  
    self.options.exclude, byte_compile_default=True)   File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 1097, in install
    rt.byte_compile(linked_files, bc_option, exclude_regex, ignore_errors)   File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 231, in byte_compile
    shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __ init__  
    errread, errwrite)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child  
    raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory dpkg: error processing fusion-icon (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Processing triggers for menu ...  
Errors were encountered while processing: fusion-icon  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to edit the dpkg `status` file manually:

```
sudo -i 
gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Locate `fusion-icon` package, remove carefully the whole block of information about it and save the file.